# JavaScript callback to get selected glyph index in Bokeh

Tags: javascript, bokeh

I've created a visual graph using Bokeh that shows a network I created using Networkx. I now want to use TapTool to show information pertinent to any node on the graph that I click on. The graph is just nodes and edges. I know I should be able to use `var inds = cb_obj.selected['1d'].indices;` in the JavaScript callback function to get the indices of the nodes (glyphs) that were clicked on, but that's not working somehow and I get the error message, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1d' of undefined`. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my code. Please note that I've defined my plot as a Plot() and not as a figure(). I don't think that's the reason for the issue, but just wanted to mention it. Also, I'm using `window.alert(inds);` just to see what values I get. That's not my ultimate purpose, but I expect that bit to work anyway.

```
def draw_graph_____(self, my_network):
    self.graph_height, self.graph_width, self.graph_nodes, self.graph_edges, self.node_coords, self.node_levels = self.compute_graph_layout(my_network)

    graph = nx.DiGraph()
    graph.add_nodes_from(self.graph_nodes)
    graph.add_edges_from(self.graph_edges)

    plot            = Plot(plot_width = self.graph_width, plot_height = self.graph_height, x_range = Range1d(0.0, 1.0), y_range = Range1d(0.0, 1.0))
    plot.title.text = "Graph Demonstration"

    graph_renderer = from_networkx(graph, self.graph_layout, scale = 1, center = (-100, 100))
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data["node_names"] = self.graph_nodes
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data["index"]      = self.graph_nodes

    graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph              = Circle(size = 40, fill_color = Spectral4[0])
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.selection_glyph    = Circle(size = 40, fill_color = Spectral4[2])
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.hover_glyph        = Circle(size = 40, fill_color = Spectral4[1])

    graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph              = MultiLine(line_color = "#CCCCCC", line_alpha = 0.8, line_width = 5)
    graph_renderer.edge_renderer.selection_glyph    = MultiLine(line_color = Spectral4[2], line_width = 5)
    graph_renderer.edge_renderer.hover_glyph        = MultiLine(line_color = Spectral4[1], line_width = 5)

    graph_renderer.selection_policy     = NodesAndLinkedEdges()
    graph_renderer.inspection_policy    = NodesAndLinkedEdges()

    x_coord = [coord[0] for coord in self.node_coords]
    y_coord = [coord[1] for coord in self.node_coords]
    y_offset = []

    for level in self.node_levels:
        for item in self.node_levels[level]:
            if self.node_levels[level].index(item) % 2 == 0:
                y_offset.append(20)
            else:
                y_offset.append(-40)

    graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data["x_coord"]    = x_coord
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data["y_coord"]    = y_coord
    graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source.data["y_offset"]   = y_offset

    labels_source   = graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source
    labels          = LabelSet(x = "x_coord", y = "y_coord", text = 'node_names', text_font_size = "12pt", level = 'glyph',
                               x_offset = -50, y_offset = "y_offset", source = labels_source, render_mode = 'canvas')
    plot.add_layout(labels)

    callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = graph_renderer.node_renderer.data_source), code =
    """
    console.log(cb_obj)
    var inds = cb_obj.selected['1d'].indices;
    window.alert(inds);
    """)

    plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips = [("Node", "@node_names"), ("Recomm", "Will put a sample recommendation message here later")]))
    plot.add_tools(TapTool(callback = callback))

    plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

    output_file("interactive_graphs.html")

    show(plot)
```

My imports are as follows, by the way:

```
import collections
import networkx             as nx
import numpy                as np

from bokeh.io               import output_file, show
from bokeh.models           import Circle, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS, Div, HoverTool, LabelSet, MultiLine, OpenURL, Plot, Range1d, TapTool
from bokeh.models.graphs    import from_networkx, NodesAndLinkedEdges
from bokeh.palettes         import Spectral4
```

I'm sorry for not posting entire code, but that would require quite a few changes to make dummy data and show other files and functions (which I should have), but I thought just this one function may suffice for the identification of the issue. If not, I'm happy to share more code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the callback is not attached to a data source. The value of `cb_obj` is whatever object triggers the callback. But only `ColumnDataSource` objects have a `selected` property, so only callbacks on data sources will have `cb_obj.selected`. If you are wanting to have a callback fire whenever a selection changes, i.e. whenever a node is clicked on, then you'd want to have the callback on the data source. [1]

However, if you want to have a callback when a node is merely hovered over (but not clicked on) that is an *inspection*, not a *selection*. You will want to follow this example:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-hover

Although it is not often used (and thus not documented terribly well) the callback for hover tools gets passed additional information in a `cb_data` parameter. This `cb_data` parameter is used as a catch-all mechanism for tools to be able to pass extra things, specific to the tool, on to the callback. In the case of hover tools, `cb_data` is an object that has `.index` and `.geometry` attributes. So `cb_data.index['1d'].indices` has the indices of the points that are currently hovered over. The `.geometry` attribute as information about the kind of hit test that was performed (i.e. was a single point? or a vertical or horizontal span? And what was the location of the point or span?)

[1] Alternatively, tap tools also pass a specialized `cb_data` as described above. It is an object with a `.source` property that the the data source that made a selection. So `cb_data.source.selected` should work. In practice I never use this though, since a callback on the data source works equally well.

Comment: Thank You very much, @bigreddot, as cb_data.source.selected['1d'].indices worked! This is such a relief! I can use it for now, but I understand using cb_obj would be the more appropriate thing to do, right? How do I attach the callback to the data source, may I ask? I see what you're saying, but it seems from other examples online that cb_obj somehow knows what glyph was clicked on and what the associated data source is. I'm obviously wrong there, so just want to know how to make it explicit that cb_obj should use the data source I intend for it to use. Thanks!

Comment: The examples in this section demonstrate attaching a callback to the data source for selections: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-selections Just as a reminder, this approach works for *selections* but does not work for *inspections* (i.e. does not work for hovers)