# Bokeh show text on click

Tags: python, bokeh

I saw this example

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file("openurl.html")

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    color=["navy", "orange", "olive", "firebrick", "gold"]
    ))

p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=20, source=source)

# use the "color" column of the CDS to complete the URL
# e.g. if the glyph at index 10 is selected, then @color
# will be replaced with source.data['color'][10]
url = "http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/@color/"
taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

show(p)
```

I would like to do something similar, instead of opening the url, I would like to show some text on the right when i click on the circle related to that circle. And the text should change when I click on another circle.

I also saw this: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-for-user-interaction-events but I couldn't change the mouse prints with some text based on the circle.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `CustomJS` instead of `OpenUrl`

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

taptool.callback = CustomJS(code="""
    var ind = cb_data.index['1d'].indices[0];
    var color = cb_obj.source.data['color'][ind];

    $('#div_id').text(color);
""")
```

more explanations see here [JavaScript callback to get selected glyph index in Bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640995/javascript-callback-to-get-selected-glyph-index-in-bokeh)